# Mxnet Bind error of lro_labels and data for image regression

Tags: regression, bind, conv-neural-network, mxnet, resnet

I use mxnet to do image regression(4 labels) by fine-tuning resnet50.

1. I changed SoftmaxOutput with LinearRegressionOutput in symbol
2. I changed image label into a number
3. I used metric=mx.metric.MSE() instead of training acc.

So the symbol is like in the last layer.

```
{
"op": "FullyConnected",
"name": "fc",
"attr": {"num_hidden": "4"},
"inputs": [[430, 0, 0], [431, 0, 0], [432, 0, 0]]
},
{
"op": "null",
"name": "lro_label",
"inputs": []
},
{
"op": "LinearRegressionOutput",
"name": "lro",
"inputs": [[433, 0, 0], [434, 0, 0]]
}
],
```

But when I run the code I have an error like simple_bind error.

simple_bind error. Arguments:
lro_label: (36,)
data: (36, 3, 227, 227)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "finetune.py", line 59, in 
for_training=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mxnet-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/mxnet/module/module.py", line 388, in bind
state_names=self._state_names)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mxnet-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/mxnet/module/executor_group.py", line 214, in init
self.bind_exec(data_shapes, label_shapes, shared_group)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mxnet-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/mxnet/module/executor_group.py", line 310, in bind_exec
shared_group))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mxnet-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/mxnet/module/executor_group.py", line 582, in _bind_ith_exec
shared_buffer=shared_data_arrays, **input_shapes)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mxnet-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/mxnet/symbol.py", line 1375, in simple_bind
raise RuntimeError('simple_bind failed')
RuntimeError: simple_bind failed

It seems the error happened in

```
mod = mx.module.Module( symbol=new_sym, context=ctx, data_names=('data',), label_names=('lro_label',)) 
mod.bind(data_shapes=[('data', (batch_size, 3, 227, 227))], label_shapes=[('lro_label', (batch_size,))], for_training=True)
```

Input and output is not same, but when I use softmax, there is no such problem.
What happened?

Answer (score 1):

I had two wrong parts:

- num_class need to be 1 instead of classification labels
- lro_label: (36,) should be lro_label: (36, 1,)